# Using cat command in Python for printing

Tags: python, linux, printing

In the Linux kernel, I can send a file to the printer using the following command

```
cat file.txt > /dev/usb/lp0
```

From what I understand, this redirects the contents in file.txt into the printing location.  I tried using the following command

```
>>os.system('cat file.txt > /dev/usb/lp0')
```

I thought this command would achieve the same thing, but it gave me a "Permission Denied" error.  In the command line, I would run the following command prior to concatenating.

```
sudo chown root:lpadmin /dev/usb/lp0
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This should work fine via `system`. Can you elaborate on "didn't work"?

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: What's wrong with opening 2 files and reading from one and writing to another?

Comment: Also, how are you running shell commands (or Python) in the kernel?!

Comment: +1 to @AlexP., but you can do this even more easily with the [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) module.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I'm just using the Python shell. I would like to use the shutil module, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "just using the Python shell". You can import and use `shutil` just as easily as `os`. They both come with Python.

Comment: surprised no one brought this up already but writing directly to the /dev is not the usual way of printing under linux.  Unless you have a really barebones linux you should have some print management service accessible via lpr command or similar.  Figure that out and call that command from python.

Comment: @george This is for a bare-bones Linux.  In any other case, I would probably use the CUPS print management system that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no reason your code shouldn't work, this probably isn't the way you want to do this. If you just want to run shell commands, `bash` is much better than `python`. On the other hand, if you want to use Python, there are better ways to copy files than shell redirection.

The simplest way to copy one file to another is to use [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile):

```
shutil.copyfile('file.txt', '/dev/usb/lp0')
```

(Of course if you have permissions problems that prevent redirect from working, you'll have the same permissions problems with copying.)

---

You want a program that reads input from the keyboard, and when it gets a certain input, it prints a certain file. That's easy:

```
import shutil

while True:
    line = raw_input() # or just input() if you're on Python 3.x
    if line == 'certain input':
        shutil.copyfile('file.txt', '/dev/usb/lp0')
```

Obviously a real program will be a bit more complex—it'll do different things with different commands, and maybe take arguments that tell it which file to print, and so on. If you want to go that way, the [`cmd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module is a great help.

Comment: I would like the program to run shell commands once it responds to certain inputs. Would bash still be better than python for this?

Comment: @user2125538: If you explicitly want to "run shell commands" rather than "do some stuff", then it may well be. But without knowing more about what you're actually trying to build, it's very hard to say.

Comment: To explain it briefly,  what I would like is a program that once it reads a certain input from a keyboard, it sends a file at a certain location to the printer.

Comment: So you _don't_ need to run shell commands, you need to print files. Let me edit my answer to show how you would write such a program.

Comment: It works, yes. Now make sure, that you are not really import whole module for one operation.

Comment: @NikolayBaluk: What do you mean by that? Importing standard library modules is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. If you're twisting yourself into knots to avoid it, you're not writing Python.

Comment: @abarnert I asked a similar question to Nikolay, but can you explain to me the difference between your solution and the command using the "opening and closing" commands Nikolay provided?

Comment: I mean "from shutil import copyfile". Even if you're "writing Python" be honestly remember about performance.

Comment: @user2125538: Using `shutil` is faster, it uses less memory, it's easier to read, it's harder to get wrong, and it's generally considered more pythonic to use the "batteries included" than to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @NikolayBaluk: I have a feeling you've never actually timed, profiled, or optimized any real-life code, if you really think the cost of `import shutil` is going to be anywhere near the cost of reading an entire file into memory unnecessarily.

Comment: @abarnert agree with you. Just don't import whole module.

Comment: @abarnert oh man... yes! it's better than a whole file in memory, but worse than 'from shutil import copyfile'. And stop talking about me, please.

Comment: What do you mean "don't import whole module"? Doing `from shutil import copyfile` is not any faster than `import shutil` (in fact, it's actually a tiny bit _slower_, but not enough that you'd ever notice). And it's generally not considered good style in real programs (although in a tiny script like this, it might be reasonable). Let me guess: do you not understand the difference between `import shutil` and `from shutil import *`?

Comment: @NikolayBaluk: OK, I'm glad you've read that. Now do you understand why you should not recommend `from shutil import copyfile` over `import shutil`?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in UNIX - everything is a file. Even devices.

So, you can just use basic (or anything else, e.g. shutil.copyfile) files methods (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

In your case code **may** (**just a way**) be like that:

```
#  Read file.txt
with open('file.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
with open('/dev/usb/lp0', 'w') as target_device:
    target_device.write(content)
```

P. S. Please, don't use system() call (or similar) to solve your issue.

Comment: but the second one is not even recommended; first way is always preferred

Comment: What you mean no recommended? Can you provide a proof? It's a basic I/O operation!

Comment: @NikolayBaluk Just out of curiousity, can you explain to me the difference between your solution and the command using the 'shutil' command?

Comment: Other than it being uglier, if your `write` method fails, there won't be any closing of the file. It's a bit of over-simplifying since the OS may take care of it of course.

Comment: @user2125538 sure, look. In my, you don't import anything (works faster and is native). With shutil, you need to import something and you can deal only with files (you can not write simple string to device), BUT it have much more convenient code.

Comment: @NikolayBaluk: I'm willing to bet that `shutil.copyfile` will be a whole lot faster than reading the whole file into memory so you can write it out. (And it will also take a lot less memory, obviously.) And the cost of importing a module is so tiny compared to the cost of copying a file (and then waiting for a printer to print it!) that it's not even going to be measurable.

Comment: @abarnert correct idea. To avoid reading whole file you may just read-write by line, but in this case, is definitely better to use shutil.copyfile.

Answer (score 0):

under windows OS there is no `cat` command you should use`type` instead of `cat` under windows

(**if  you want to run `cat` command under windows please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71998867/2723298 )

```
import os
os.system('type a.txt > copy.txt')
```

..or if your OS is linux and cat command didn't work anyway here are other methods to copy file..
with grep:

```
   import os
    
   os.system('grep "" a.txt > b.txt')
```

*`' '` are important!

copy file with sed:

```
os.system('sed "" a.txt > sed.txt')
```

copy file with awk:

```
os.system('awk "{print $0}" a.txt > awk.txt')
```