# Linux function in Jupyter Notebook running in Windows

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

I am writing this code in my jupyter notebook but it is not working.

```
!tail -n 10 Customers.csv
```

The error is

```
'tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am also attaching an image for the reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDd2i.png)

Comment: Are you sure `linux` is related? Windows never heard of tail

Comment: Yes, you aren't using Linux as @Roi is pointing out. Exclamation point doesn't mean it sends it to a linux shell necessarily. Be default it just sends the command to run to your system's main command line basis and on your Windows machine's current set-up that isn't Linux. It is probably DOS given what it is showing. I don't know what the dos equivalent of `tail` is. If you want to switch to using Linux then probably follow what Daniel is suggesting or search around for advice along those lines specifying what version of Windows you are using, installing with Anaconda, etc.

Comment: read and apply my answer it is possible to run linux command under windows without wsl.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `sed, awk, grep, tar, wget` exc.. from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html .
and I installed `tail, chmod, mkdir` exc.. commands from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm
I tested, commands are running in jupyter notebook under **windows OS** but there is a mini problem: For example After running the sed command, it leaves a file with a name starting with sed, ( it is like `sed_fdgdfgdf` ) it is necessary to delete these files.
[image: tail in cmd]

NOTE: Download complete package and run *.exe file
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539900/using-bash-commands-in-jupyter-notebook) post recommends installing [WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) or [Git Bash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash).